# Cannot disable lock-screen

Tags: lock-screen, 14.10

I'm trying to disable the lock-screen feature that requires me to enter a password when waking up the screen after being idle. I've turned off every setting I can find related to password reqiurement but I'm still being prompted. I still want the screen to blank when idle, just not lock the machine when it does so.

Under `System Settings > Brightness & Lock`, I have:

```
Lock: OFF
Require my password when waking from suspend: unchecked
```

Under `System Settings > Security and Privacy > Security`, I have:

```
Waking from suspend: unchecked
Returning from blank screen: unchecked
```

Is there some other setting I missed that's causing my screen to lock when it's blanked?

Answer (score 0):

There is usually another option that states lock screen after x minutes

Could be a separate application like Light Locker [usually found in System Settings] or xscreensaver (and if I remember right there may even be an xlockscreen).  I never auto lock my screens so it has been awhile since I last worked on something like this in-depth.  If it is essentially a base install I would check Power Management settings (see paragraph below :-) )

Could also be Power Manager [again in System Settings] once opened click Extended and there is a checkbox there to "Lock Screen When Going for Suspend/Hibernate" which you would want to uncheck.

Hope that helps.